# Max number of familiars?

Tags: blood-brothers

In Blood Brothers, what's the max number of familiars you can hold? My current limit is 50. Is there anything I can do to increase the max count?

Answer (score 2):

As you progress through the games quests, you will unlock **more formations** and your capacity will increment by **2 each time you trigger that reward**. When I played I had a capacity of 62 familiars.

Answer (score 0):

I heard the limit was removed. I have 74.